# How does one use induction to prove that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k2^{n-k+1} = 2^{n+2}-2(n+2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I am unsure how to use induction to prove this expression. I am not even sure how to begin. My textbook says to start with a "left hand sum" and "right hand sum" but I don't know what this means.
Can someone with more experience in discrete mathematics explain how to do this?

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k2^{n-k+1} = 2^{n+2}-2(n+2)$

Comment: Without induction, let $[m]=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and $S$ denote the set of $(x,y,T)$ where $x,y\in[n+1]$ and $T\subseteq [n+2]$ s.t. $x<y$ and every element of $T$ is larger than $y$.  If $y=k+1$, then there are $k$ choices of $x$ and $2^{(n+1)-(k+1)}=2^{n-k}$ choices of $T$, so $|S|=\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot 2^{n-k}$. 
$$\phantom{a}$$ On the other hand start with a subset $U\subseteq [n+1]$ s.t. $|U|\ge2$, and then set $x<y$ to be the two smallest elements of $U$, and $T=U\setminus\{x,y\}$.  Therefore $|S|=2^{n+1}-1-(n+1)=2^{n+1}-(n+2)$.   Your question is about $2|S|$.

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the base case.  Is it true for $n=0$ (or $n=1$)?

Then assume it's true for $m$: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m k2^{m-k+1}=2^{m+2}-2(m+2).\tag1$$

Now show it's true for $m+1$:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} k2^{m+1-k+1}=2^{m+1+2}-2(m+1+2).\tag2$$

Note that from taking $(2)-2\times(1)$, you need to show

$$(m+1)2=2m+2,$$

which is easy.

Answer (score 1):

We start with the base step. For $n=1$ the LHS becomes
$$1 \cdot 2^{1-1+1}=2=8-6=2^{1+2}-2(1+2)$$
So, it is true for $n=1$.

For the inductive step, assume that it is true for $n=m$, that is
$$\sum_{k=1}^m k2^{m-k+1}=2^{m+2}-2(m+2)$$

We must show that it is true for $n=m+1$. Note that
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k2^{(m+1)-k+1} &= \sum_{k=1}^m k2^{(m+1)-k+1} + (m+1)2^{(m+1)-(m+1)+1} \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^{m} k2^{m-k+1} + 2(m+1)
\end{aligned}

By our inductive hypotesis, we get
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k2^{(m+1)-k+1} &= 2(2^{m+2}-2(m+2)) + 2(m+1) \\
&= 2^{m+3}-4m-8+2m+2 \\
&= 2^{m+3}-2(m+3)
\end{aligned}

So, it is also true for $n=m+1$.